# How to find cause of WPF Window location change?

Tags: c#, wpf, systemevent, window-position

Whenever I resume my computer from hibernation, it seems that my `Window`'s location shifts to the top of the screen.  I have the following to log my Window location:

```
        LocationChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Logger.Info($"{Top},{SettingsHelper.Instance.Settings.WindowTop}");
        };
```

`WindowTop` is a property that is loaded into memory from a file that keeps track of where the `Window` last was before it was closed.  Whenever this prints on startup, both values are correct as expected.  However, after resuming from hibernation, this prints a 0 for the actual value, while the setting value is still the same.  That eliminates an incorrect setting value being loaded from being the cause.

I'm also attempting to reload the settings whenever the computer resumes from hibernation:

```
    private void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Mode == PowerModes.Resume)
        {   
            LoadUiSettings();
        }
    }

    private void LoadUiSettings()
    {
        Left = SettingsHelper.Instance.Settings.WindowLeft;
        Top = SettingsHelper.Instance.Settings.WindowTop;
    }
```

This also does not resolve the issue.  However, when I add in a `MessageBox` before the load, it'll show the `Window` at the incorrect location, then it'll properly load the settings and switch to the correct one.  Since I moved my window away from the original location, I can see that on resume, it'll fix the location correctly, then somehow, after unlocking my computer, it'll move itself to `Top = 0`.  Strange thing is that `Left` is not plagued by this issue at all.  All the usages of both properties in the solution are identical.  This does not happen with a vanilla WPF application, so I'm not really sure how to investigate this further.  Strangely enough, this does not occur if I just lock the computer manually, and not by hibernating.

Is there a way to find out what is changing my `Window`'s `Top` property somehow?

Edit: my workaround is to use `SystemEvents.SessionSwitch` and `SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock` and call `LoadUiSettings` from there, but that's still a bandaid around the actual problem.  I'd still like to figure out what's causing it and solve it at the root.

Edit 2: If the Window isn't currently visible, setting it still does not change the actual position.  I temporarily overrode the Visibility, then performed the following:

```
            while (Math.Abs(Top - SettingsHelper.Instance.Settings.WindowTop) > 0.1)
            {
                Top = SettingsHelper.Instance.Settings.WindowTop;
            }
```

I see the Window show up for a split second while it's waiting to be adjusted, then after it disappears again, and I toggle the visibility manually through the UI, it's at the top again.  Toggling it manually when it's already in the correct location does not yield this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Pertinent to your specific question (i.e. finding the CAUSE of the problem, but not asking for the solution), the answer may be found using the following code snippet to perform analysis of WPF `Window` position change corresponding to `PowerModeChange` event:

```
SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerChange;

private void OnPowerChange(object s, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    switch ( e.Mode ) 
    {
        case PowerModes.Resume:
        // Log the position as it's done in your example
        Logger.Info ("Mode Change: Resume");
        Logger.Info($"{Top},{SettingsHelper.Instance.Settings.WindowTop}");
        break;
        case PowerModes.Suspend:
        Logger.Info ("Mode Change: Suspend");
        Logger.Info($"{Top},{SettingsHelper.Instance.Settings.WindowTop}");
        break;
    }
}
```

Upon finding the root cause of your problem (namely, which event causes the `Window` dislocation), you may develop relatively simply fix, like for e.g. re-positioning the `Window` on `PowerModes.Resume` event.

Hope this may help.

Comment: Not sure if you posted this before or after my edit (I'm assuming after since you edited the tags after my latest one), but I mentioned that it changes sometime between resuming and unlocking the computer.  I have a workaround in place already, but I want to find out how to fix it at the root.

Comment: I am responding to your original question. It's a bit unclear: did you resolve the actual issue of Window dislocation caused by hibernation, and secondly, did you get the answer to your question by using either the code snippet in my answer, or your amended code: please clarify. Best regards,

Comment: No, I did not use your snippet at all.  The issue is still unresolved because I don't know what causes it, but I do have a workaround that I put in place for it currently.